# Python Argsparser add a single argument to subparser without a name

Tags: python, argparse

There is extensive documentation for how to do a bunch of complex things, whereas I can't seem to find something very simple - 
I have a script with some actions:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='do this')
parser_act_one = subparsers.add_parser('actone')
parser_act_one.add_argument('--function', type=str)
parser_act_two = subparsers.add_parser('acttwo')
parser_act_two.add_argument('--function', type=str)
```

Since they only take one argument a piece I would like to do the equivalent of `parser_enmod.add_argument()` without a name which doesn't seem to work.

Edit: 
To clarify: 
What I would like to run is:

```
python my_script.py actone 'special_name'
```

instead of:

```
python my_script.py actone --function='special_name'
```

Comment: *which doesn't seem to work*. What did you do and what happened then?

Comment: It does not recognize it as an argument, it works fine with the --function, but I'd like to avoid that redundancy if at all possible.

Comment: A subparser is just a regular parser, really; you can add positional arguments just fine. Please show us your code that didn't work.

Comment: How do I add one argument without naming it explicitly for commandline? I'll edit the question also.

Comment: Please look at the [first example in the argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#example).  It shows the definition of a *positional argument* which is what you want (no `--`).  With `--` you get an *optional argument*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to name your positional arguments, but you simply don't start them with the `--` prefix to make them positional instead:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='do this')
parser_act_one = subparsers.add_parser('actone')
parser_act_one.add_argument('function', type=str)
parser_act_two = subparsers.add_parser('acttwo')
parser_act_two.add_argument('function', type=str)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Demo')
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='do this')
>>> parser_act_one = subparsers.add_parser('actone')
>>> parser_act_one.add_argument('function', type=str)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='function', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser_act_two = subparsers.add_parser('acttwo')
>>> parser_act_two.add_argument('function', type=str)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='function', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] {actone,acttwo} ...

Demo

positional arguments:
  {actone,acttwo}  do this

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
>>> parser_act_one.print_help()
usage:  actone [-h] function

positional arguments:
  function

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>>> parser.parse_args(['actone', 'some_filename.txt'])
Namespace(action='actone', function='some_filename.txt')
```